Probem in counting all figures in a folder
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcounter{NumFiles}
%\setcounter{NumFiles}{-1} % fileName_0.pdf ... fileName_?.pdf

\newboolean{stop}
\whiledo{\NOT\boolean{stop}}{
  \stepcounter{NumFiles}
  \IfFileExists{D:/folder_1/picture_\theNumFiles.jpg}{}{
    \addtocounter{NumFiles}{-1}
    \setboolean{stop}{true}
  }
}

\begin{document}
  They are \theNumFiles pictures.
\end{document}

I took the aforementioned code from Get number of files in folder (all credits to @AlexG) and tried a slight modification since I am interested the total number of all pictures in a certain folder. But one thing I don´t understand: Why does the pictures have to be in consecutive order, i.e. if the images are not consecutive (e.g. picture1, picture2, picture44 instead of picture1, picture2, picture3,...) then the total number is not correct, how can this be fixed? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

you have chosen to loop in consecutive order and stop at the first one not found

In a current latex you can use l3sys-query to iterate over all the files matching a pattern such as *.jpg or *.png (or folder_1/picture_*.jpg)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{l3sys-query}
\newcounter{NumFiles}


\QueryFiles{*.png}{\stepcounter{NumFiles}}


\begin{document}
  There are \theNumFiles\ pictures.
\end{document}


Thanks a lot for your help!

Regarding the above answer I have another question: If I replace the line \QueryFiles{.png}{\stepcounter{NumFiles}} by the following line:\QueryFiles{D:/KG_Petra/KG_year_2023_24/pictures_of_pupils/theme_1/nameA.png}{\stepcounter{NumFiles}} I get the wrong answer "0 pictures". I am using a Windows 10 system together with TeX Live 2024. When I add all pictures into the folder where the above code is saved everything works very nice! The reason why I am using the long version of the file path is that I have to move around the picture folder on several computer. Where is my mistake? Thx!

this is documented, l3sys-query has to be quite restricted in order for texlive to allow it to be used without using --shell-escape even though it is doing a call to the shell to use ls or dir (depending on the platform) so in particular it will only allow searching below the working directory  you can not use absolute paths and you can not use ../  @mario1000

@mario1000 I will remove the D:... suggestion from the answer as it's wrong, sorry

Thanks again for the help, so I will add the pictures into the same directory as the tex-file!
